# Not able to use token-refresh in my Angular7 project

Tags: angular7, refresh-token, angular-oauth2-oidc

I want to use refresh-token functionality in my angular7 code, tried alot, not able to resolve with the help of existing solutions.

```
<html>
<body>
  <script>
     parent.postMessage(location.hash, location.origin);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'silent-refresh.html'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'silent-refresh.html'
>       at

Path of Silent-refresh placed in project (angular.json)
    `"assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/silent-refresh.html"
            ],`
Code to call refresh token automatically 
      `this.oauthService.setupAutomaticSilentRefresh()`